# Issue with how to close a pop up in watir

Tags: ruby, watir

After clicking a button, a new Windows alert opens.  I tried to use this code:

```
 browser.button(:name => 'OpProvisionalCreate').click     

 browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")  

 browser.window(:title => "Message from webpage").use do
   browser.button(:id => "close").click
 end
```

But I am getting an error message:

```
:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `window' for #<Watir::IE:0x1a76990> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a window method included?

Comment: Are you using watir-classic or watir-webdriver? Please provide link to the page, the similar one, or relevant HTML.

Comment: i using a watir-classic

Comment: Are you using an older version of watir-classic? I believe IE#window was added in a more recent release.

Comment: i am using a watir-classic. Sorry but link will not work because its a corporate application the HTML is '<td class="fkeys"><button type="button" class="fkeys" id="F2" name="OpProvisionalCreate" onClick="submitForm(this.name, 'createForm')">F2<br><b>Prov Res</b></button></td><TD width="100"></TD>' sorry if i dont have any more info

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the popup? Based on the code you are trying, it is not clear what type of popup you are trying to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of watir-classic. `Browser#window` method was added in watir-classic 3.0.0. But closing a JavaScript popup should be done with the help of Alert API:

```
# this will open the popup? Use #click_no_wait in that case.
browser.button(:name => 'OpProvisionalCreate').click_no_wait
# close the popup
browser.alert.close
```

Read more from the [Container](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Container#alert-instance_method) and [Alert documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Alert). If you want to use the Alert API mentioned above, then you need to use watir-classic 3.1.0 or newer.

Comment: did the update to Version 3.4.0 and its working fine. thanks again

Comment: I am currently using watir 5.0.0 and this doesn't seem to work. @Jarmo Can you confirm if this answer is still valid?